# I bought a domain from Arvixe without hosting, how can I set up email?

Tags: email, domain-registration

I bought a domain from Arvixe, without any hosting plan. In the domain settings, I didn't find anywhere to set up email accounts. Do I have to buy their hosting plan to have email accounts?

Comment: Short answer. Very likely. E-mail does not just come from the sky. It may be that your host or another can handle e-mail for your domain. There are services specifically designed for e-mail only. As well, many host options can allow this too. Go seek these out. We cannot make recommendations here. But this should be easy to find and set-up.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted their customer service and was told that emails do not come with a domain only purchase. You have to buy their hosting plan

Answer (score 1):

Buying a domain entitles you to your own www.example.com. Many domain providers will let you keep your domain name for a year. The option you must have with your purchase is the ability to assign an IP address to your domain so that a server is contacted when the domain is requested on the internet. The IP address association with a domain name can be easily demonstrated through the use of a command-line utility PING.

As for the rest of the services such as email, Its best that you rent a server with email software installed on it. If you have enough money and you want a full stack, you could go for a dedicated server with a cPanel/WHM or equivalent software installed then you can have tons of options including email address options, FTP, subdomain creation, logging and more.

Your server provider must provide you with at least one usable IP address you can associate your domain name to.

Once all that is done, give abut 24-48 hours for the domain to be setup correctly across the entire internet.

Comment: "Many domain providers will let you keep your domain name for a year."  What does that mean?  Is there some process by which they may let you keep it for less than the year you paid for?

Comment: I believe theres a possibility that one could run into a company that allows one to rent a domain which lasts less than a year. It's always a good idea to check complete terms and conditions of any service used to make sure everything is alright before purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue is getting your domain into the Domain Name System so that the internet knows where different services are (mail, website).

If you buy hosting it comes with DNS services.  If you don't want hosting, some companies will include DNS when you buy a domain, other hosting companies will sell you DNS only hosting.  Once your domain in in the DNS you then have plenty of options for email e.g. gmail, a mail account elsewhere, your own mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless promised "free email with domain name registration" you do need hosting services to have @domain.com email service.

Answer (score 0):

**No. You won't need to buy email. Just use some free email for domains provision**

If you wish to use emails on domain for your personal use and or for a small number of people, you wont't need to spend on professional email or any kind of hosting if you wish to use it for a few accounts or limited number of space.

There are free email for domains providers like

- [Pawnmail](https://pawnmail.com/) -
  Which allows 2 GB Storage forever free for any number of accounts you wish to create. It allows us to login through a roundcube webmail interface or we can setup an email client.
- [Zoho for domains](https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html) -
  Which provides 5 GB each for upto 10 user accounts in a domain.

**The steps you need to follow for both the above or any other service are**

1. Setup MX Records in your DNS
2. Create accounts in the control panel
3. Wait for dns propagation
4. Login using the webmail or setup an email
   client.